# Why does unet have classes?

Tags: python, pytorch, image-segmentation

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F


class double_conv(nn.Module):
    '''(conv => BN => ReLU) * 2'''
    def __init__(self, in_ch, out_ch):
        super(double_conv, self).__init__()
        self.conv = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(in_ch, out_ch, 3, padding=1),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(out_ch),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.Conv2d(out_ch, out_ch, 3, padding=1),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(out_ch),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True)
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.conv(x)
        return x


class inconv(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_ch, out_ch):
        super(inconv, self).__init__()
        self.conv = double_conv(in_ch, out_ch)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.conv(x)
        return x


class down(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_ch, out_ch):
        super(down, self).__init__()
        self.mpconv = nn.Sequential(
            nn.MaxPool2d(2),
            double_conv(in_ch, out_ch)
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.mpconv(x)
        return x


class up(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_ch, out_ch, bilinear=True):
        super(up, self).__init__()

        #  would be a nice idea if the upsampling could be learned too,
        #  but my machine do not have enough memory to handle all those weights
        if bilinear:
            self.up = nn.Upsample(scale_factor=2, mode='bilinear', align_corners=True)
        else:
            self.up = nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_ch//2, in_ch//2, 2, stride=2)

        self.conv = double_conv(in_ch, out_ch)

    def forward(self, x1, x2):
        x1 = self.up(x1)
        diffX = x1.size()[2] - x2.size()[2]
        diffY = x1.size()[3] - x2.size()[3]
        x2 = F.pad(x2, (diffX // 2, int(diffX / 2),
                        diffY // 2, int(diffY / 2)))
        x = torch.cat([x2, x1], dim=1)
        x = self.conv(x)
        return x


class outconv(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_ch, out_ch):
        super(outconv, self).__init__()
        self.conv = nn.Conv2d(in_ch, out_ch, 1)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.conv(x)
        return x


class UNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, n_channels, n_classes):
        super(UNet, self).__init__()
        self.inc = inconv(n_channels, 64)
        self.down1 = down(64, 128)
        self.down2 = down(128, 256)
        self.down3 = down(256, 512)
        self.down4 = down(512, 512)
        self.up1 = up(1024, 256)
        self.up2 = up(512, 128)
        self.up3 = up(256, 64)
        self.up4 = up(128, 64)
        self.outc = outconv(64, n_classes)

    def forward(self, x):
        self.x1 = self.inc(x)
        self.x2 = self.down1(self.x1)
        self.x3 = self.down2(self.x2)
        self.x4 = self.down3(self.x3)
        self.x5 = self.down4(self.x4)
        self.x6 = self.up1(self.x5, self.x4)
        self.x7 = self.up2(self.x6, self.x3)
        self.x8 = self.up3(self.x7, self.x2)
        self.x9 = self.up4(self.x8, self.x1)
        self.y = self.outc(self.x9)
        return self.y
```

When I was reading UNet architecture I have found that it has `n_classes` as output.

```
class UNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, n_channels, n_classes):
```

but why does it have `n_classes` as it is used for image segmentation?

I am trying to use this code for image denoising and I couldn't figure out what will should the `n_classes` parameter be, because I don't have any classes.

Does `n_classes` signify multiclass segmentation? If so, what is the output of binary UNet segmentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer

> Does n_classes signify multiclass segmentation?

Yes, if you specify `n_classes=4` it will output a `(batch, 4, width, height)` shaped tensor, where each pixel can be segmented as one of `4` classes. Also one should use [`torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html) for training.

> If so, what is the output of binary UNet segmentation?

If you want to use binary segmentation you'd specify `n_classes=1` (either `0` for black or `1` for white) and use [`torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss.html#bcewithlogitsloss)

> I am trying to use this code for image denoising and I couldn't figure out what will should the n_classes parameter be

It should be equal to `n_channels`, usually `3` for RGB or `1` for grayscale. If you want to teach this model to denoise an image you should:

- Add some noise to the image (e.g. using [`torchvision.transforms`](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/transforms.html))
- Use `sigmoid` activation at the end as the pixels will have value between `0` and `1` (unless normalized)
- Use [`torch.nn.MSELoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.MSELoss.html) for training

### Why sigmoid?

Because `[0,255]` pixel range is represented as `[0, 1]` pixel value (without normalization at least). `sigmoid` does exactly that - squashes value into `[0, 1]` range, hence `linear` outputs (logits) can have a range from `-inf` to `+inf`.

> Why not a linear output and a clamp?

In order for the Linear layer to be in `[0, 1]` range after clamp possible output values from Linear would have to be greater than `0` (logits range to fit the target: `[0, +inf]`)

> Why not a linear output without a clamp?

Logits outputted would have to be within `[0, 1]` range

> Why not some other method?

You could do that, but the idea of `sigmoid` is:

- help neural network (**any logit value can be outputted**)
- first derivative of `sigmoid` is gaussian standard normal, hence it models the probability of many real-life occurring phenomena (see also [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/163152/237147) for more)

Comment: I saw this sigmoid final layer several times, and I can't figure it out. Why not a linear output and a clamp? Why not a linear output without a clamp? Why not some other method?

Comment: @Gulzar updated my answer, does it make more sense?

Comment: I don't understand what logits have to do with a linear layer output. If there is no sigmoid, and the output physics is really pixel intensity, there is no point that I see going through a logistic function. For example, the very basic autoencoder examples online on MNIST also work with a linear final layer (or with sigmoid), and linear layers don't have vanishing gradients problems. So, I still don't understand the use of sigmoid for non logistic data.

Comment: @Gulzar it has nothing to do with vanishing gradient. In case of classification logits are the outputs from linear layer (sigmoid transforms logits into probabilities). Those are in the +/- infinity range. Your pixel values are [0, 1] and you use MSE as a criterion (unless pixels are only 0 and 1 which is usually not the case). Your neural network can output any real value and sigmoid will simply squash it, hence __it does not have to output bounded values between 0 and 1__ (as this task is much harder and easy to get wrong, e.g. predict pixel value being 1.02, obviously wrong).

Comment: @Gulzar remember that end goal of OP is denoising instead of segmentation, in case of segmentation appropriate loss is enough in PyTorch.